# addAttributeToFilter with dropdown values

Tags: collection

Given a dropdown attribute such as color:

```
color:
   Red
   Green
   Blue
```

When loading a product collection how can i load the collection based on either red, blue or green values without knowing the actual option ids?

For example:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('color', 'Red');
```

Will not work as i need to know the option id.

This means loading the attribute and getting the options id - which is going to be innefficient for a large number of attributes/options.

Answer (score 7):

by default you cannot filter by color (or any dropdown attribute) like that. The cleanest way to do it is to get the option id for the `red` color.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$options = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color')->getSource()->getAllOptions(); //get all options
$optionId = false;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if (strtolower($option['label']) == 'red'){ //find the Red option
        $optionId = $option['value']; //get it's id
        break;
    }
}
if ($optionId) { //if there is an id...
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', $optionId);
}
```

But this could backfire if you have 2 options with the same name.

There is also this option:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->where('color_value = ?', 'Red');
```

But it works only when you have the flat catalog enabled and when the `color` attribute is set to be "Used in product listing".
I don't recommend this approach. It can get you into trouble.

Comment: One of the things I'd like to add to this is you can "cache" the heavy part (Getting options ID and Label relation) for efficiency - http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/03/how-to-cache-custom-data-into-magento/ , and another thing would be change the case of letter to UPPER or lower before comparing.

Comment: @SubeshPokhrel. You are right. Caching is a good idea. I was just trying to prove a concept. I also changed the comparison to use lowercase strings. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Marius's answer that works well for us...

```
<?php
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        'click_and_collect',
        array(
            'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('click_and_collect')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId('Yes')
        )
    );
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($collection as $product): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><span class="product-name"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></span></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```